# Wear OS: Get User Input

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os, messaging

I'm trying to get text input from a user in a Wear OS app. What I'm looking for is a similar interface to the screenshots below:
[Google Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfCXi.png)
[Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0jfd.png)

I have not found anything in the documentation how to achieve something like that. The closest I came across was to use notifications as demonstrated here: https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/d192c9d2000e43f63cca3eb1b9af05cf2e2ee867/Notifications
This is quite similar to the screenshots from above, the problem however is that this just generates notifications the user then still has to click on. If there is a way such that the notification opens automatically, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was already asked here and that solves the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294785/17818420

The following code sends an intent to get the user input

```
val remoteInputs: List<RemoteInput> = listOf(
    RemoteInput.Builder("quick_reply").setLabel("Quick reply").build()
)
val intent: Intent = RemoteInputIntentHelper.createActionRemoteInputIntent()
putRemoteInputsExtra(intent, remoteInputs)
startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
```