# TextField Password on Wear OS Compose app with erasing bug

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, wear-os

I'm trying to use both BasicTextField or TextField in wear os compose to make a toggle password field. But, sometimes when trying to erase the password on the physical watch, the mask isn't being erased. Does anyone know what can it be?

NOTE: This bug only occurs when using KeyboardType.NumberPassword. The bug does not occur when using neither KeyboardType.Password nor KeyboardType.Number

Video: https://imgur.com/a/91FzXFA

My code:

```
    var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var passwordVisible by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier
           .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
           .fillMaxWidth(),
        colors = customTextFieldStyle(),
        value = password,
        onValueChange = { password = it },
        singleLine = true,
        placeholder = {
           Text(
               modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
               text = "Enter your password",
               fontSize = 12.sp,
               textAlign = TextAlign.Center
           )
        },
        visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible) {
            VisualTransformation.None
        } else {
            PasswordVisualTransformation()
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
            //my code here
            defaultKeyboardAction(ImeAction.Done)
        })
    )
```

My wear compose version: "1.3.0-alpha06"

I tried using both BasicTextField and TextField but it didn't work. I tried to use a custom class to transform the password and it didn't work and I also tried to do the manual mask using the string.repeat() method, but the code had more bugs, it started having problems with not saving the password and the password being erased when swipping to dismiss the keyboard.

With this current code, everything works fine, except for the bug in this imgur video that sometimes, when pressing the delete button on the keyboard, the mask is not visually erased. And I also tried using a FocusRequester to force the keyboard focus to be cleared and request focus again within the `onValueChange` method, but it didn't work.

I also tried following this answer to use GBoard activity https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294785/10359104 but I couldn't find a way to show just numbers and with password mask transformation

Comment: Link to the Issue on the Google issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/313591199